# Update task status where all doers marked it as done

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

[image: schema]

I need to make a cron script for my application, which will update statuses of tasks, where all performers have finished work on their specific tasks.

`` UPDATE `tasks`
SET status_id = 4
WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `task_id` FROM `task_user` WHERE __ALL PERFORMERS OF TASK HAVE STATE_ID = 2__) ``

"Performers" have the `role_id` = 2 and their `state_id` varies from 1 (work on task is not finished) to 2 (work on task is finished)

please, help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and a `having` clause to get the ids you want:

```
UPDATE `tasks`
    SET status_id = 4
    WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `task_id`
                   FROM `task_user`
                   GROUP BY task_id
                   HAVING SUM(STATE_ID = 2) = COUNT(*)
                  );
```

The expression `SUM(STATE_ID = 2)` counts the number of rows in `task_user` for each `task_id` that have "2" for the state.  The `= COUNT(*)` says "all of them have this status."

EDIT:

To include `role_id`:

```
UPDATE `tasks`
    SET status_id = 4
    WHERE role_id = 2 AND
          `id` IN (SELECT `task_id`
                   FROM `task_user`
                   WHERE role_id = 2
                   GROUP BY task_id
                   HAVING SUM(STATE_ID = 2) = COUNT(*)
                  );
```

Comment: thx a lot

```UPDATE `tasks`
SET status_id = 4
WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `task_id`
FROM `task_user`
GROUP BY task_id
HAVING SUM(state_id = 2) = SUM(role_id = 2)```